# 'Remote procedure call failed' when opening Excel .xlsm in VBScript

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, sap-gui

I've been running into trouble opening Macro-Enabled Excel Workbooks through a VBScript that runs overnight (works with extracting data from SAP, into Excel).

It used to work all the time, but recently it keeps throwing a

> Windows Script Host error 800706BE "remote procedure call failed"

on the third line of code below:

```
Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.application")
ExcelApp.Visible = true
Set MyBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("N:\Automation_Materials\Open AutoPO Issues\Scripts\A_scriptPackage\AB_MacroController.xlsm")
Set ExcelApp = Nothing
```

The file doesn't open, which causes some problems for the rest of the automated process. All the excel file should do is run some VBA to edit other workbooks that have fresh data. It's a few manipulations, then this VBA just closes up shop and exits everything. Problem is, it never even opens!

Comment: hmmm, maybe `CreateObject("Excel.Application")`?

Comment: what happens when you try this code inside Excel VBA (for a test)? Also, when in Excel VBA, try using early binding as well by adding a reference to Excel ...

Comment: has the version of Excel been changed on your workstation?

Comment: @OurManinBananas The version hasn't changed recently. The weird thing is that it doesn't seem to happen every time... but I can't seem to find anything else that could be changing it.

Comment: I can only suggest testing your code inside Excel VBA, both early binding, and late binding...

Comment: Do you run the script through an elevated command prompt? Sounds like a UAC permission issue to me.

Comment: @lankymart I actually run this script through SAPGUI, as the rest of the script carries out tasks on that GUI. I'm not very fluent in VB, I've only recently begun diving into scripting for automating office tasks.

Comment: @rick-owens: what happens when you try this code inside Excel VBA (for a test)? Also, when in Excel VBA, try using early binding as well by adding a reference to Excel